# Alternative to patching core library source and header files

Tags: core-libraries, build

I am following a DIY guide that requires me to patch two arduino core library files: `HID.cpp` and `USBAPI.h`. This is not really practical for many reasons. I am not a native C programmer, but I am sure there are better ways to achieve the same without messing directly with system files. How can I override system library files without modifying the originals?

Comment: That all depends on what the modifications are you need to do...

Comment: @Majenko principally it adds a third device description (HID Remote) to the two devices that are described in those two files (Keyboard and Mouse). I can upload a diff.

Comment: Can't you just place a copy in the sketches folder and alter this local copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there *really* isn't any way of doing that other than modifying those files. The good news is that it is perfectly viable to make the modifications under a different "core" and then [amend boards.txt](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/wiki/Platforms1) with the core containing the modifications.